# How to enter new when in full screen mode using Chrome and macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-mojave

Using Chrome on macOS Mojave (10.14), hitting:

<kbd>⌘ + CTRL + F</kbd> then,
<kbd>⌘ + SHIFT + F</kbd>

Will put Chrome in Full Screen mode, and hide the Toolbar.

How does one enter a new URL now?

<kbd>⌘ + L</kbd> will appear to do nothing.

Hitting <kbd>⌘ + T</kbd> will open a new tab as expected, but not allow one to enter a URL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I was in fact wondering about that myself. I almost posted in apple.stackexchange but at the last minute thought it was a Google thing than an Apple thing.